# i need a solution if the user change his keyboard or his mood changed in keystroke dynamic?

Tags: algorithm, keystroke, biometrics

my graduation project is about keystroke dynamic authentication for user and i have some problems (the users change their keyboard , Distractions happened to them change their writing characteristics) in the identification phase . if their is an algorithm over come this problems or any idea to be made in training phase for the system  .

thanks :)

Comment: I don't mean to be rude - as you say this is your graduation project. Did you do some conventional research on the topic? If so, what methods or common problems did you find?

Comment: Added biometrics and keystroke tags.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_dynamics#Authentication_versus_identification): Keystroke dynamics is part of a larger class of biometrics known as behavioral biometrics; their patterns are statistical in nature. It is a commonly held belief that behavioral biometrics are not as reliable as physical biometrics used for authentication such as fingerprints or retinal scans or DNA. The reality here is that behavioral biometrics use a confidence measurement instead of the traditional pass/fail measurements. As such, the traditional benchmarks of False Acceptance Rate (FAR) and False Rejection Rates (FRR) no longer have linear relationships.

Or, in plain English, you're going to have to have a long identification phase so that you can determine the statistical patterns, rather than any individual pattern.